# how to map nullable column to a non nullable variable?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, mapping, nhibernate-mapping

if we have a table that already has a fields marked as allow null (in sql server), and for some reason i want to map these fields to a class in c# code but keep my variables as non nullable (discrete values), and if i is null in db give this variable its default value in c#.

for example:

```
Table Employee (
  ID int Not NULL,
  Name nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
  Age int NULL)
```

Now i want this table to be mapped to this class

```
class Employee {
   public int ID {get; set;} 
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;} 
}
```

i have no problem to use either linq to sql, or nhibernate, either will do the job.

can anyone give me a solution for this

Ah, BTW, if the Age field in db is null I want the Age variable to take the default value of int (for example 0)

Answer (score 1):

Just map the first two columns as you normally would and with the nullable int use the following...

```
if (Age.HasValue) return Age.Value else return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your linq2sql model, you could name the Age field RawAge and make it private. Then make a partial class Employee that defines Age as

```
  public int Age {
    get { RawAge.HasValue ? RawAge.Value : default(int); }
    set { RawAge.Value = value; }
  }
```

A problem though, is that you now have no way to set the value of Age to null. You can't map the default value of int back to null because it is a valid non-null value for the field.

Comment: But this mean I have to have two properties for each field in the database, is there a better way ?

Comment: The dbml code generator makes the private property for you. You just need to write the little wrapper like in my answer. Since RawAge is private, using code won't see it, and it won't show up in intellisense. Technically there are two properties as you say, but only one is visible.

Comment: I tried this solution, but the datacontext (in Linq to sql), unable to map the private members even if i decorate it with the ColumnAttribute, any Ideas ??